# change bootstrap tooltip position

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have following code snippet to change the bootstrap tooltip position.

But I am not sure what is meant by "my" , "at" and left+15 etc.

Please explain so that I can change the values to position my tooltip.

```
   $( "#btn1" ).tooltip({ position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" } });
```

Answer (score 1):

[**`.position()`**](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position) is **specific** to **[jQuery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com)**.

The option `my` defines which position on the element being positioned to align with the target element horizontally. A single value such as `"right"` will be normalized to `"right center"`, `"top"` will be normalized to `"center top"` (following CSS convention). The acceptable horizontal values are `"left"`, `"center"`, `"right"`. The acceptable vertical values are `"top"`, `"center"` and `"bottom"`. Each dimension can also contain offsets, in pixels or percent. For example, `"right+10 top-25%"`. Percentage offsets are relative to the element being positioned.

The option `at` defines which position on the target element to align the positioned element against horizontally. Percentage offsets are relative to the target element.

The default for both options is `"center"`.

You can find more information about `.position()` **[here](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)**.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap plugin methods take a single argument, not two. This method call:

```
$('#keterangan').attr('title', 'Keterangan wajib disi!').tooltip('show', {
    placement: 'right'
});
```

is incorrect. Instead, you should keep the on change function the way you had it, and call:

```
$('#keterangan').tooltip({ placement: 'right' });
```

earlier to set up the tooltip options (such as when the document is ready).

The other, possibly simpler, alternative would be to add data-position="right" to the element that the pop-up is being shown on.

Answer (score 0):

The code is from jqueryui, not bootstrap.

Complete explanation of your code sample is in the next links

Tooltip widget position: http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position

Parameters for position: http://api.jqueryui.com/position/